# WCF - C# - SOAP How to change port name?

Tags: c#, wcf, soap

Im new in WCF. I've been trying to do this but no success yet.

I have to expose a service but I'm having some troubles trying to change the name of the port in the WSDL.

[image]

This is my Webconfig

[image]

Sorry about my english and I'll realy appreciate the help.

Comment: Did you resolve the problem, and why you want to change the port? I think you want to change the EndPoint address?

Comment: Yes I did! I wanted to change the port because my client needed it.

Answer (score 1):

I did it. If you need to solve this problem all you have to do is this:

1. This is how the system.serviceModel tag of the webconfig looks like.
   [image]
2. This is how my service contract looks like
   [image]
3. This is the class PortNameWsdlBehaviorExtension that inherit from BehaviorExtensionElement. This class is specified in the webconfig

I most add that my service and the PortNameWsdlBehaviorExtension class are in the name space myNameSpace.

[image]